# Error CDO w.server 2012 r2

Tags: asp

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema en un windows server 2012 R2, cuando trato de enviar mail via asp clasico me da error al tratar de asignar cualquier característica del CDO, da error 500. Al principio creia que no me salian los correos pero realicé la prueba con programa de mail y los correos salen del servidor y llegan al receptor, entonces comencé a dejar con comentarios los diferentes pasos del asp y el error da justo cuando trato de asignar algo en cualquier linea dentro del with , tambien trate de hacerlo asignando directo como en la ultima linea que muestro.

Este codigo funciona correctamente con server 2008 R2 pero el nuevo servidor falla , alguien me puede indicar por donde o que es diferente el server 2012 R2

gracias

```
Set objCDOSYS=Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With objCDOSYS
.BodyPart.charset = "unicode-1-1-utf-8"
.From = lv_emisor
.To = mail_des
.Subject = "NO RESPONDER "
.HTMLBody = lv_mensaje & "<br>" & lv_emisor & "<br>"
.send
End with

objCDOSYS.From = lv_emisor
```